# Checking the existing of a file by url inside native php router

Tags: php, routes, wampserver

I would like to know how could I check the existing of a file by a given url inside native php router (index.php) here is what I've tried :

```
function does_file_exists($url){
  try{
    $headers = get_headers($url);
    if(is_array($headers))
    {
      return (stripos($headers[0],"200 OK") || stripos($headers[0],"304 OK")) ? true : false;
    }
    else
    {

    }
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {

  }
  return false;
}
```

Inside (index.php)

```
$url = "http://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(does_file_exists($url))
{
  $ext = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  if(in_array($ext, $unauthorized_file_type))
  {
    Redirect('404.php');
    exit();
  }
  else
  {
    header("Location: $url");
    exit();
  }
}
```

The page takes long time to output a message 'Warning: get_headers(http://[website]/test): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed' may be due to reccursion. How can I solve that without .htaccess file?

Comment: If you're requesting a website that's internal (it exists on the same machine that's making the request) .. You're going to have to add an enrty for that domain into your hosts file `/etc/hosts` ..  Should look something like  `127.0.0.1      domain.com`

Comment: If you're resting a website that's external... You won't have any control over the response rate of their website.  It looks like you have the simplest method already: return str_contains(get_headers($url)[0], "200 OK");

Comment: @James I do routing of all pages inside index.php, for that reason I check the existence of  internal files inside my own server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the file_exists command in PHP.See the following example:

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . "/views/dashboard.php")) {


          include __DIR__ . “/views/dashboard.php”;

}
```

`__DIR__` here refers to the directory of the currently-executing script, so you will want to make all paths relevant to that.

Comment: But file_exists function would get executed inside the router script (index.php) and will call that script recursively!

Comment: Just add a catch for that case to the if statement. You should never allow a user to load index.php through the router, /index.php should always load a view that is somewhere else (because index.php is the router, not the homepage)

Comment: And without the non ascii quotes `“` and `”` of course as they will cause compilers errors

Comment: Yea, sorry. Wrote that with my phone :/

Answer (score 0):

str_contains(get_headers($url)[0], "200 OK") works fine but it's resource-intensive since it will always try to download the file, even if it's already in your browser's cache.  You can see from bloated server logs that this is happening, even if the site isn't apparently being slowed up.

My theatre's website shows a thumbnail image against every show on the main pages, so there can be over 50 of them.  For better or worse, I'm using Wordpress, which always prepends the home URL to every file it stores in its database.  An easy way to ensure file_exists() works as intended is to use this:

```
function sgs_file_exists ($file) {
    return file_exists(str_replace(home_url(), $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], $file));
}
```

If your site doesn't use Wordpress, replace home_url() above with the absolute home URL, eg. 'http://mywebsite.com' - ie. within quotes and no trailing foreslash.

file_exists() will work fine with relative URLs by prepending with the $_SERVER bit, eg:

```
file_exists ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/subdir/subsubdir/filename.htm');
```